# How to get a binary file from a remote php script response?

Tags: java, php

I'm calling a script that gives me a binary file (12345.cl), with binary data. The script is done, and it's working, if I paste it on the navigator I get the binary file.

Now I have a problem: How I transform the response of the script into a binary resource to use it in my app?

For the moment, i have this code:

```
 public void decodeStream( String mURL ){  
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(mURL).openStream(), BUFFER_IO_SIZE);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(baos, BUFFER_IO_SIZE);
        copy(bis, bos);
        bos.flush();
```

Then, I have a BufferedOutputStream with the response, but I don't know how to transform it into a binary resource to use it

**I need to obtain a datainputstream with the file** but I don't know how to achieve it

Comment: Do you want to write an php script to take the respone or what ?:)

Comment: no, i have the PHP script, is on the mURL parameter, the PHP script gives me a binary file, i want to receive it with java

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
public void decodeStream( String mURL, String ofile ) throws Exception {
    InputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(mURL);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        in = urlConn.getInputStream();
        out = new FileOutputStream(ofile);
        int c;
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        while ((c = in.read(b)) != -1)
            out.write(b, 0, c);
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a binary file, not a text file, also i need to obtain a datainputstream with the file, did you know wich changes i must do to obtain it?

Comment: I believe you're capturing output of a URL which is a PHP script, something like `http://domain.com/foo.php`. Now are you saying this PHP script's output is binary such as an image or music file rather that some text?

Comment: I have updated the answer to read raw bytes from mURL stream and write it to a file. Please check.