# How to create a DataInputStream with the content of a binary file obtained from a remote php script?

Tags: java, datainputstream

I'm calling a script that gives me a binary file (12345.cl), with binary data. The script is done, and it's working, if I paste it on the navigator I get the binary file.

Now I have a problem: How I transform the response of the script into a binary resource to use it in my app?

For the moment, I have this code:

```
 public void decodeStream( String mURL ){  
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(mURL).openStream(), BUFFER_IO_SIZE);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(baos, BUFFER_IO_SIZE);
        copy(bis, bos);
        bos.flush();
```

Then, I have a BufferedOutputStream with the response, but I don't know how to transform it into a binary resource to use it

**I need to obtain a datainputstream with the file** but I don't know how to achieve it

Comment: Question posted twice: [How to get a binary file from a remote php script response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923867/how-to-get-a-binary-file-from-a-remote-php-script-response)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `DataInputStream` is not an implementation of XDR.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wanted to read the file as a binary resource without having to save it you could just wrap the input stream from the URL in a DataInputStream instead of a BufferedInputStream and then use the DataInputStream's `int read(byte[] b)' or`byte readByte()` functions to get the data.

If you now have the file saved locally though, you can use create a FileInputStream and use the `int read(byte[] b)` function to read in the byte data.